# Separating only English language support from a TTF font file type

Tags: fonts, truetype

I have a TTF font file type for a particular font. The file size for the same is coming out to be 31 MB. Upon further inspection I saw that it has support for all languages(around 17 other languages). These are of no use to me as I only need English for my iOS app. Also,it is a custom font.

Is there a way that I can separate all other language support and just keep English from the font file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any programmatic way to do so, but you could use a font-editor like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/).

Right click on the glyph you want to remove and select "clear".
To select multiple lines of glyphs, use your keyboard arrows while pressing shift.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! This process is a little tedious but it worked!

Comment: @Mayanksagar You're welcome, don't forget to mark as "accepted" if this answer did solve your problem.